# SQLite - select from table a based on result of calculation of relevant rows in table b

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

i have two tables, "topics" (table a) and "topic_votes" (table b).
each row in table b has an attribute, "vote" (boolean).

i need to select rows from topics and order them by the sum total of all relevant rows in topic_votes with vote=true subtracted by all relevant rows in topic_votes with vote=false.

for example, for one row in "topics" there are four total rows in "topic_vote" , 3 with vote=true and 1 with vote=false, in this case the "sum_total" will be 2 (3 - 1).

how can i implement this in sqlite?

Comment: please show some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Don't you know how to relate the two tables in a query? Or don't you know how to aggregate rows and count? It may be good to show the query you got so far and tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the difference in vote count for each topic in subquery and then join it with topics table like this:

```
select t.*
from topics t
join (
    select topic_id, 
        sum(case when topic_vote = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) -
        sum(case when topic_vote = 'false' then 1 else 0 end) diff
    from topic_votes
    group by topic_id
) v on t.topic_id = v.topic_id
order by v.diff desc, t.topic_id;
```

I assumed the relation column is topic_id. Feel free to set it to whatever column name you have.

Comment: Well written query. Be aware of nulls, though; make this `count(case when ...` or add `else 0`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Updated. . . Thanks.

Comment: thanks that did the trick! but now the query doesnt include topics which dont have topic_votes. how can i include these topics as well?